# How to add "active" class to navigation link, if you are on a single post page in Jekyll

Tags: navigation, jekyll, state

My [personal site](http://bit.ly/1nhoVyl) is developed over Jekyll. Also, I have implemented `active` navigation logic. So if I would click on "Journal", it will take me to the list page where you can find all posts.

Navigation Items:

1. Home
2. Journal
3. Projects
4. About
5. Contact

Now I am looking for a solution where I can give active class to "Journal" while I am on a single post page or reading a post.

You can consider `current-post-ancestor`, `current-menu-parent` or `current-post-parent` post classes in WordPress for better understanding of this question.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each post has a `page.path` variable like `_posts/postName.md`. So with your code, you can use `page.path contains "_posts/"` like this :

```
<li {% if page.url == '/journal/' or page.url == '/post.html/' or page.path contains "_posts/" %} class="active"{% endif %}>
  <a href="{{ site.baseurl }}/journal">Journal</a>
</li>
```

Note : it seems that `{% if page.url == '/journal/' || page.url == '/post.html/' || page.path contains "_posts/" %}` is not working.

Comment: Might be due to some other permalink settings meaning its not quite working for and and not the other

Answer (score 0):

If 'Journal' is the page 'mysite.com/journal' and your posts are on 'mysite.com/journal/postdate/postname' you can check if the first part of the URL equals the menu item, like this:

```
{% assign url_parts = page.url | split: '/' %}
<li {% if url_parts[1] == 'journal' %}class="active"{% endif %}> ... </li>
```

Source: http://jekyllcodex.org/basics/

This might require a custom permalink. Info about custom permalinks can be found on the [same page](http://jekyllcodex.org/basics/).